# How to avoid changing parameter order

Tags: f#

I am currently doing some of the excercises from [exercism.io](http://exercism.io). One of the excercises is summing up all numbers in a sequence that are a multiple of one or more numbers from a different sequence. Splitting the problem into smaller functions seemed like a good idea and i came up with this:

```
let multipleOf m n =
    n % m = 0

let anyMultipleOf (m: int list) n =
    m
    |> Seq.exists (multipleOf n)

let sumOfMultiples m n =
    [1..n-1]
    |> Seq.filter (anyMultipleOf m)
    |> Seq.sum
```

The idea being, that i can use partial application to "bake in" the `m` parameter into my `(any)multipleOf` functions. But this code doesn't work the way i want it to, because `Seq.exists (multipleOf n)` actually applies `n` as my `m` parameter.

How can i refactor this code without having to reverse the parameter order of my `multipleOf` function?

---

Note: I want a solution that uses my `multipleOf` function inside my `anyMultipleOf` function. This solution works, but doesn't reuse my first function:

```
let anyMultipleOf (m: int list) n =
    m
    |> Seq.exists (fun x -> n % x = 0)
```

Comment: Both `multipleOf` and `anyMultipleOf` should really have the parameter in reversed order though. parameters are defined from the more general to the more specific. There is point to reuse a `(any)MultipleOf x` more than the way it currently is

Comment: My thought process was exactly the other way around. Like checking whatever values i have against a partially applied sequence: `let anyMultipleOfMyNumbers = anyMultipleOf [3;5;7]`

Comment: This one also works well: `let filterMultiplesOf5 numlist = numlist |> Seq.filter (multipleOf 5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *did* type in a suggestion to use `flip`, but the obvious thing to do is this:

```
let anyMultipleOf (m: int list) n =
    m
    |> Seq.exists (fun x -> multipleOf x n)
```

`flip` is a nice tool to have, but pipelines of flipped functions are painful to read.

Comment: While it does the same as flip, i like your solution better. It's more explicit in where the parameters go and it's also easier to read when having even more parameters.

Answer (score 3):

While it's unclear to me why you don't redefine `anyMultipleOf` to take the the list as the last argument, you can always use `flip`:

```
let flip f x y = f y x
```

This function [exists in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip), but not in FSharp.Core, which is the reason you'd have to define it yourself.

As an example, `flip anyMultipleOf` returns a function with the type `int -> int list -> bool`, which, if I understand the question correctly, is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can define yourself a function which just do that :
Takes a function and 2 arguments in reversed order and return the result of applying the arguments in the right order to the function

```
let flip f y x = f x y
```